# Meeting invites not able to be forwarded by recipients

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I’m a receptionist in a large organisation where I manage meeting room bookings. My profile has owner permissions on 3 different profiles. We work on the recent 365 outlook and. The issue currently is, when I send an invite from the other profiles in a “on behalf of” ... status it does not allow the invite to be forwarded, the staff I work with need to forward these meeting invites to their teams and they can not forward them, it prompts them to save , when doing so it still does not forward. Ive checked my permissions and it seems fine, the forward tab drop down doesn’t have an allow or forward option. Is there a solution? I called our IT and they only had a work around and not an actual solution.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, we could forward the meeting request normally except the sender uncheck "Allow forwarding" Have you checked the response option?

[image]

> it prompts them to save

Did the recipient also work with Outlook?  Could you post the detailed error on the recipients' client?

Comment: Does your issue have any update?